# AWS Lambda schedule - can we disable/enable schedule from within lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, scheduling

I have set of 3 AWS lambda functions (volume backup monitoring functions). I have created 3 functions so that each function will have only 1 loop , this way execution time (and billing) is less. Each lambda function puts call to next lambda function in SQS. I also have a lambda function that picks up message from queue and executes requested lambda function.

My question is about scheduling. I can schedule Lambda1 to run at desired frequency (say every 10 minutes). How do I schedule the lambda that reads queue ? I can schedule to run it every n minutes but once queue is empty there is no need for its execution till end of day. Can I somehow disable the AWS lambda schedule from within lambda function ? If not - what are alternatives ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need queue (SQS) functionality? If not I suggest you use SNS (compared to a kinesis stream it is also way cheaper), which can trigger lambdas directly. That way you avoid having a lambda that looks into a queue and then triggers other lambdas, which feels like an antipattern to me.

Beware: If you should use SNS your lambdas have to be idempotent, since SNS has an at-least-once guarantee (you could end up recieving the message multiple times) inside AWS.

Answer (score 0):

SQS can't trigger Lambda directly. Lambda have to poll SQS using Cloudwatch Timer. But I know it doesn't solves your problem. One option you can try, but i can't suggest it as the best option and it's not a cost effective one.

> While posting the message to SQS add trigger in SQS that will post the
>   message to SNS. From SNS now the lambda function will be triggered or
>   better you can directly post the message to SNS and trigger the
>   Lambda.

Another better option is you go with `kinesis`. Because it's more cost effective by creating shards and which result in batch processing. Also it has the trigger for Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use AWS SDK, specifically the methods `enableRule()` and `disableRule()` of the `CloudWatchEvents` class (you will need IAM permissions for `events:DisableRule` and `events:EnableRule`).

Sample code to deactivate a rule:

```
// rulename is the name of the CloudWatch Event rule, not the ARN
let deactivate_cloudwatch_rule = (rulename) => {
  let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
  let cwe = new AWS.CloudWatchEvents({ region: "us-east-1" });
  cwe.disableRule({ Name: rulename }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
  });
};
```

To see your the list of rules, go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home#rules .